# Migrate tables in django from a read-only database

Tags: python, django, django-models, readonly, django-migrations

Is there a way to migrate all tables from an oracle read-only database to django?
So basically I don't want to make any modification to my database. I just want to extract information from  it. 
From what I found till now, is a way by using routers but I don't know how exactly to use it.

Thanks, any help will be appreciated

DB: oracle
Django version: 2.2.12
python: 3.6
cx-Oracle: 7.3.0

Answer (score 0):

you should use `model.Meta.managed=False`

you will define a normal model and set this attribute in it's `meta`

```py
class AModel(models.Model):

    field1 = ...
    field2 = ...

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "name_of_already_created_table"
```

if by router you mean [Database routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) it should only be used if you have more than one database to work with.

you should write your models based on the tables and columns that you have in your oracle db and add the `managed=False` to each of them separately. 
so if you have for example three tables in your database you will write three separate models for it in your `models.py` file. this way django wont create the tables and just trys to read those tables also you need the `db_table` attribute and value of it should be the name of your table in the database

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when i run the command python "manage.py inspectdb > models.py" my models.py file is empty. Should I add these lines you posted into my models file? Also if I run the command: "python manage.py migrate" I got the following error: "Unable to create the django_migrations table (ORA-01031: insufficient privileges"(because of the read-only access)

Comment: I cannot create the models manually because is a huge database. That's why I wanted to  migrate all tables into models and then to work with them. Is there another way to create those models without the need for write access?

Comment: no you can not migrate tables to models it's one way only.